# Adding colon after two numbers using Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query in Big-Query using standard SQL.

I have a column in my table where time is presented in this format: **170519**

What I want to do is to add colon **(:)** after every two numbers to get results like this: **17:05:19**

How do i do this?

I have been searching but have not been able to find a solution to this. Maybe I'm not searching with the correct words?

Thanks for the help!

***EDIT:***

So @Gordon Linoff 's answer works for one column.

Now how do I use that in when combining two columns?

Here is my code where I get a syntax  Error:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", PARSE_DATE('%d%m%Y',
        Date1)), '  ',(PARSE_TIME("%H%M%S",
        Time1)) AS Date_Time
  FROM
```

Comment: you are at least missing closing bracket

Comment: Tried with that, then i get a new error:


No matching signature for function CONCAT for argument types: STRING, STRING, TIME. Supported signatures: CONCAT(STRING, [STRING, ...]); CONCAT(BYTES, [BYTES, ...]) at [2:3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '09052019' date1, '170519' time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '10052019', '091020'
)
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d%m%Y%H%M%S', CONCAT(date1, time1)) date_time,
  CAST(PARSE_DATETIME('%d%m%Y%H%M%S', CONCAT(date1, time1)) AS STRING) date_time_as_string
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row     date_time               date_time_as_string  
1       2019-05-09T17:05:19     2019-05-09 17:05:19  
2       2019-05-10T09:10:20     2019-05-10 09:10:20
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that you can try (copy and paste this into the editor in https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery):

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION InsertColons(s STRING) AS (
  CONCAT(SUBSTR(s, 1, 2), ':', SUBSTR(s, 3, 2), ':', SUBSTR(s, 5, 2))
);

SELECT s, InsertColons(s) AS result
FROM (
  SELECT '123456' AS s UNION ALL
  SELECT '170519'
);
```

The `SUBSTR` function selects parts of the string, e.g. the first two characters at ordinal 1, then the first two characters at ordinal 3, then at ordinal 5, before using `CONCAT` to combine the parts.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(c, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(c, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(c, 5, 2)
FROM
    -- Use your own table in the FROM statement instead of this fake one
    (SELECT '170519' as c ) as q1
```

> Returns 17:05:19

or with your data:

```
SELECT LEFT(timo, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(timo, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(timo, 5, 2)
FROM
    table1
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner when it comes to SQL and programming in general. Could you explain what you have done? I still don't have a grip on how double selects work. Find it confusing.

Comment: it's just an example to fake a table with a column of your format, plug in your table instead of the second `select`

Comment: Haha sorry still don't get it (Newbie). If my table is called: table1 and the column is called: timo. How do i do this? Also I will use the column to combine it with  another column using CONCAT.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn it into a `time` data type rather than a string:

```
select parse_time('%H%M%S', '170519')
```

If it starts out as a number:

```
select parse_time('%H%M%S', cast(170519 as string))
```

If you want to format this as a string, you can then format the time.  For instance, the following would put this in HH:MM format:

```
select format_time('%H:%M', parse_time('%H%M%S', cast(170519 as string)))
```

I am a fan of storing things in the correct type.

Comment: Works when used for itself! But I get an error when I use this to combine two columns using CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CONCAT(SUBSTRING('170519', 1, 2), ':', SUBSTRING('170519',3, 2), ':', SUBSTRING('170519',5, 2))
```

this gives you proper ans like 17:05:19

Comment: Hello Ashwini, since it's your first answer, usually It's a good practice to explain how and why the code you posted work, and also encapsulate your code snippet into triple backtip (`) to give a correct format output